# Сложение положительного и отрицательного числа в двоичной системе исчисления

Tags: c#, binary

Язык программирования c#
Заданы положительное и отрицательное число в двоичной сс (последовательность нулей и единиц).
Составить программу вычисления суммы двух чисел.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
            string str2 = Console.ReadLine(); 
            Console.WriteLine(dec_to_bin(bin_to_dec(str1)+bin_to_dec(str2))); 
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static Int32 bin_to_dec(string a)
    {
        double b = 0;
 
        for (double i = a.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         b += Convert.ToDouble(a.Substring(Convert.ToInt16(i), 1)) * Math.Pow(2, i);
             return Convert.ToInt32(b);
        }
    static string dec_to_bin(Int32 a)
        {
            string b = "";
             while (a != 0)
            {
                b = (Convert.ToInt16(a % 2)).ToString() + b;
                a /= 2;
            }
             return b;
        }
}
```

Я написала этот код, но раньше никогда не сталкивалась с отрицательными числами в двоичной сс, я хочу понять правильно ли написан мой код и если есть ошибки помогите пожалуйста исправить их.

Comment: Правила написание отрицательных двоичных чисел есть разные, какие у вас? Вы не привели ни примеров ввода, ни результатов работы, не ожидаемых результатов. Не указали, работает код или не работает. Что можно здесь ответить? Пока видно, что вы без какого-либо смысла используете double как индексатор в цикле, используйте целый тип, вам надо int16, вот и используйте short тогда. Код отформатирован в вопросе тоже волшебно.

Comment: насчёт double, я думаю что это попытка "пофиксить" то, что `Math.Pow(2, i)` возвращает double)). По-этому стоит сказать про приведение к инту

Comment: Если отрицательные числа представлены в дополнительном коде, то в данной задаче никаких отличий в работе с ними от положительных не будет

Comment: @aepot 
В задании тоже не указано они только сказали что это будет последовательность 1 и 0
Мой код работает при сложении двух положительных чисел
Например: если сложить 101 и 100 ответ 110
Моя проблема в том, что я не имею понятия как ввести отрицательное двоичное число

На счет написания отрицательных двоичных чисел, не могли бы Вы сами привести пример?

Comment: @MBO т.е мой код будет работать?
Можете привести пример одного положительного и одного отрицательного числа в двоичной сс
и результат их сложения

Comment: Я без понятия, какие правила записи отрицательных чисел нужны. Если в лоб, то откройту Windows калькулятор, переключите в режим программиста и там есть перевод в двоичную систему счисления. Но там используется https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4, то есть разрядность имеет значение. В случае с математикой запись может быть другая, например знаком может быть лидирующий ноль. То есть число, начинающееся с 1 положительное, с 0 - отрицательное. А что именно у вас - загадка.

Comment: Вот еще ссылка https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations